# QGIS points to lines using another line layer for reference

Tags: qgis

I have a CSV file with lat/long points and dates associated with the points.  The points were recorded locations of PIT tags in fish on certain dates.

I'd like to be able to confine the points to path tool to another line layer (stream flowline paths).

Right now, if I run the points to path, grouping by fishID and ordered by recorded location date, it works as it's supposed to, but the path isn't confined to the stream line.  Obviously.

Are there any automated tools to do this or do I need to modify the generated lines by adding vertices manually along the stream paths?

Comment: I think that the answer depends on how many fish points you have.  If you have relatively few points, a simple, low-tech solution might be to manually  move them to the stream location by editing.  Inelegant, but effective.  If you have more points than patience, an automated solution may be more appropriate, but it might require an up-front learning curve.

Comment: A few hundred.  Getting closer thanks to David's answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can access or generate a polyline layer of the stream path(s), you could use the `Snap Geometries to Layer` tool to edit your output from `Points to path`.

Your `Input layer` will be the path you generated using `Points to path`. Your `Reference layer` will be the stream path polyline. You'll have to set the `Tolerance` and `Behaviour` based on your specific datasets. Hopefully this will get you a path polyline which follows the stream geometry.

Comment: So this got me a lot closer.  One issue I'm having w/ snap geometries is that I've got some points that moved a long distance across 2 streams, so it wants to connect those points via a straight line that seems to disregard the stream path layer.

Comment: Adding to this.  It seems like if the distance between points is too far it wants to shortcut and just throws a straight line between those points ignoring the reference line.  I "think" I just need to play with the tolerance and other options or reduce the points in the reference line.

Comment: Please keep us posted on your progress!